# SwiftUI List row's not resising to fit contents

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui

I have a List View with 1) a header view, 2) dynamic ForEach views, and 3) a footer view. My issue is that the first row, in which the header view lies, won't resise to fit its contents. The code for the main view is below:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            self.headerView(size: geometry.size)
        }
        ForEach(self.user.posts, id: \.self) { post in
            Text(post.title)
        }
        Text("No more posts...")
            .font(.footnote)
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

This is the view which I am trying to achieve:

[image: mockup]

This is what I have so far...:

[image: actual]
[image: hierarchy]

If it's any consolidation, the header view displays fine if it's outside of the list, however, that's not the view I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

*P.S: Apologies for the huge images, I'm not sure how to make them appear as thumbnails...*

Comment: why are you ignoring the safe area?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri I want the list to extend to the edges of the screen, as in the mockup.

Comment: I havent used swiftUI too much but i do not think you should be ignoring the safe area... the list will always expand to the edges of the screen unless you say other wise

Comment: also you have incorporated your header into your list.. not sure if that is the intention but that will make it harder to achieve what you want

Comment: @JulianSilvestri Ignoring the safe area is required for the list's view rectangle to extend to the edges of the screen — from above the status bar to below the home bar. The reason the header must be contained in the list is so that it can scroll with the other content. If I were to implement this in UIKit, I would've simply used a UITableView and set the first cell's contents to the header view.

Comment: hmm so you want your header to be part of the list so it scrolls with the list? You Dont want the header to be static at the top?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri Exactly. Think Twitter, or Facebook...

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `Sections` for similar purposes (sections allow to have different configuration of each), like

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        Section {
           // << header view is here with own size
        }
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()) // << to zero padding

        Section { // << dynamic view is here with own settings
            ForEach(self.user.posts, id: \.self) { post in
                Text(post.title)
            }
        }
        Section { // footer view is here with own size
            Text("No more posts...")
               .font(.footnote)
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Comment: the trouble is, that it will be still some left padding in the row ... that is why i use second GeomertryReader inside the List row, even-though its proxy value is not used at all. see my answer and test it yourself

Comment: thank for .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets() !!! I never use it before ...

Comment: Thank you Asperi this is great. I'd tried numerous approaches to automatically minimise List height when row height is dynamic (not known), none of which worked. This neatly solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using GeometryReader is fine, but it should be used the proper way!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // to get the size of view, we are going to use the width later
        GeometryReader { p in
            List {

                GeometryReader { _p in
                    // put your image or whatever ...
                    // and set the frame width
                    Color.red.frame(width: p.size.width, alignment: .center)
                }
                // and finally fix the height !! to work as expected
                .frame(height: 100)

                Text("By by, World!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had a similar issue and simply had to move the GeometryReader outside of the List like you've done here. After that, I used the geometry.size as an input to my views in the list which are initialized with a var size: CGSize.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple list view that change it's height automatically with the help of "SwiftUIIntrospect" pod.

The pod:

```
  pod 'SwiftUIIntrospect'
```

ListDynamicHeight code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUIIntrospect

struct ListDynamicHeight<Content>:View where Content:View {
    @State private var listContentHeight:CGFloat = .zero
    /// minHeight must be >= 1
    var minHeight:CGFloat = 1
    @ViewBuilder var content:Content
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            content
        }
        .scrollView { scroll in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                listContentHeight = scroll.contentSize.height
            }
        }
        .frame(minHeight: minHeight, idealHeight: listContentHeight)
    }
}

private extension View {
    func scrollView(_ scrollView: @escaping (UIScrollView) -> ()) -> some View {
        introspect(.scrollView, on: .iOS(.v15, .v16, .v17)) { scroll in
            scrollView(scroll)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListDynamicHeight(minHeight: 10) {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}
```

And there is also a Dynamic TextView I created (with placeholder if you like) that works perfectly with the list:

```
struct TextView: View {
@FocusState private var isInFocus:Bool
@Binding var text: String
var placeholder = ""
var shouldShowPlaceholder:Bool { text.isEmpty && !isInFocus }
var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            if shouldShowPlaceholder {
                Text(placeholder)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.leading, 6)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isInFocus = true
                    }
            }
            
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .colorMultiply(shouldShowPlaceholder ? .clear : .white)
                .focused($isInFocus)
        }
    }
}
```

Put everything together:

```
struct ListAndTextView:View {
    @State private var text = ""
    var placeholder:String = "Your Comment here..."
    var body: some View {
        ListDynamicHeight {
            TextView(text: $text, placeholder: placeholder)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListAndTextView()
}
```